# Open p12 files on ios device

Tags: ios, swift, uti, smime

I have this requirement to download .p12 file(certificate) from a vendor and make it available on my app for the user to install it on to his device.
Now If I attach a .p12 file to email and when the recipient clicks on the file on iphone it will start installing I am just trying to get the same behavior.
As of now in my app I am able to download the p12 file and store it in the apps documents directory.

```
func saveCert(serialId : String){
        let source = "https://myhost.com/serialId"
        let url = NSURL(string: source)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if (error == nil) {
                let statusCode = (response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode
                print("Success: \(statusCode)")
                let filename = self.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.p12")
                print(filename)
                data?.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)
                let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(filename) {
                    print("File exists")
                } else {
                    print("File not found")
                }
            }
            else {
                print("Faulure: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
            }
        });
        task.resume()
    }
```

Now i need to open this file so user will be taken to install profile screens. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecPKCS12Import) is what you want to look at.

and here is an example of how to use it

```
import Security

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

var resourcePath:String = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
resourcePath = resourcePath.stringByAppendingString("/dummy.p12")

if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(resourcePath){
    let p12Data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: resourcePath)!
    let key : NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
    let options : NSDictionary = [key : "password_for_certificate"]
    //create variable for holding security information
    var privateKeyRef: SecKeyRef? = nil
    
    var items : CFArray?
    
    let securityError: OSStatus = SecPKCS12Import(p12Data, options, &items)
}
```

Hope that gets you most of the way there.

**Edit:**

After doing more research, I found [this lib](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith) that will help you do everything you are looking to do.

Give it a try.

Comment: Hi Cripto, Thank you for the info, per your message I now made the code above work and the SecPKCS12Import call is successful. That means got the p12 file and password and was able to open it with password and have the cert details in items array reference. But what i need is to install this p12. I am totally new please help.

Comment: Look at my new answer.

Comment: Hi Cripto, i have a small question regarding to the above code block. It worked fine with Swift 2.2 & 2.3. But after if migrated to Swift 3.0, the `SecPKCS12Import(p12Data, options, &items)` throw out ` -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()`, which indicate unrecognized selector sent to instance `blabla`. It would be a big favour if you know how to fix it on swift 3.0?